# Is it possible to fly with AntMiner in a hand luggage?

Tags: travel

Question maybe for https://travel.stackexchange.com/

But maybe Bitcoiners will know - have you ever flew with AntMiner in a hand luggage?

Does airport security ask any questions?

Comment: It just looks like a generic piece of computer equipment, and people fly with those all the time.

Comment: OK, I was worried...

Answer (score 1):

These questions are much better posed to the TSA.

> **Computer Parts**
>
> You may transport this item in carry-on or checked baggage. For items
>   you wish to carry on, you should check with the airline to ensure that
>   the item will fit in the overhead bin or underneath the seat of the
>   airplane.
>
> To help officers get a clear look at your bag and reduce the need for
>   additional screening, we suggest you pack your bag in neat layers
>   (layer of clothes, layer of electronics, layer of clothes, layer of
>   shoes, etc.) and wrap cords tightly around electronics items.
>
> Even if an item is generally permitted, it **may be subject** to
>   additional screening or **not allowed** through the checkpoint if it
>   triggers an alarm during the screening process, appears to have been
>   tampered with, or poses other security concerns. The **final decision**
>   rests with TSA on whether to allow any items on the plane.

See: http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=computer%20parts